# How to measure the speed of a vehicle?

Tags: android

I am an absolute beginner at Android. I was planning to make an app that measures the speed of vehicle during the journey if the app is open and to suggest gear shift and fuel consumption based on the speed. Also other features are there like navigation, play music etc. But stuck at getting speed of vehicle. Please someone help me with the complete code from getting runtime location permissions(if needed) to setting the speed to a textview. i have already gone through many posts on StackOverflow and other google searches and tried some but getting errors that I can't make any sense of.

Note- I have already taken permission like ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION in Android Manifest file.

Comment: Location object has a getSpeed() method

Comment: were not here to suuply you code.... show your code and maybe we can help you figure out why getSpeed displays 0.0. Good luck

Comment: My current code doesn't contain any part of the given problem related code. I tried many but deleted them. So I didn't upload any code. Thanks

Comment: @DroiDev Yeah I know that as I have gone through documentation of Location on Android Developer but in its constructor it requires an argument called String provider that I couldn't understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the GPS you would be able to get a speed measurement for the user. The location manager would be able to provide that information. Something like this should do the trick, but go ahead and experiment with the different values it can provide you.

```
LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) this
                .getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

LocationListener locationListener = new LocationListener() { 
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) { 
        location.getLatitude();
        Toast.makeText(context, "Current speed:" + location.getSpeed(),
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) { 
    } 

    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) { 
    } 

    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) { 
    }
};
locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0,
                           0, locationListener);
```

Comment: Hi this isn't working. Its showing any toast. I have taken the speed and stored it into a float variable and then I am showing it in a textview. Both are not working.